# OS upgrade error - Windows server 2019 to WIndows server 2022 - In place upgrade method

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, operating-system, upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade the OS of my Windows instance from 2019 to the Windows Server 2022 version using the In-place upgrade method. I've attached a volume containing Windows 2022 installation media to the instance and performed the update. But the upgrade failed showing the following error:

```
0xC1900101 - 0x30018
The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase with an error during SYSPREP_SPECIALIZE operation
```

How can I overcome this issue?

I upgrade the drivers first and afterward upgraded the domain controller schema to the latest as the server is hosting a domain controller.
Next, I attached the volume containing Windows 2022 installation media to the instance. Then I ran the following command on PowerShell to perform the upgrade:

```
.\setup.exe /auto upgrade /dynamicupdate disable
```

The installation proceeds after selecting the version but the installation failed after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to old PV drivers. What worked for me was the following:

1. Uninstall the EC2Config service (If installed).
2. Install **EC2Launch v2 agent** (https://s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/amazon-ec2launch-v2/windows/amd64/latest/AmazonEC2Launch.msi)
3. Install the latest **AWS PV Drivers** (https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-windows-drivers-downloads/AWSPV/Latest/AWSPVDriver.zip)
4. Restart the instance and try to upgrade it again.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, i found buried in the logs an error about the Remote Desktop Role.  I removed that role, upgrade in placed worked flawlessly, then re-added the role.

Hope it helps someone!